# how to simplify undefined check?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to simplify JSON object check for undefined values:

```
  {
    body: {
      data: {
        names: [
          {
            firstName: 'John'
          },
          {
            firstName: 'Johnn'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

So if I do it like this then it throws an exception if names is an empty array []:

```
body?.data?.names[0]?.firstName
```

So should I go old way like this?

```
  if (
    body &&
    body.data &&
    body.data.names &&
    body.data.names.length > 0 &&
    body.data.names[0] &&
    body.data.names[0].firstName
  ) {
    // ....
  }
```

Comment: `body?.data?.names?.[0]?.firstName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `undefined` check using [`optional chaining (?.)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) and [`nullish coalescing (??)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) operators like the following way:

```js
const data =  {
    body: {
      data: {
        names: [
          {
            firstName: 'John'
          },
          {
            firstName: 'Johnn'
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  };

//test
const firstName = data?.body?.data?.names?.[0]?.firstName ?? 'Unknown';

console.log(firstName);//'John'

//test: undefined
const dataWithoutNames = {
  body: {
    data: {}
  }
};

const unknownName = dataWithoutNames?.body?.data?.names?.[0]?.firstName ?? 'Unknown';

console.log(unknownName);//'Unknown'
```